# Is it normal for rigid body simulation to be too slow?

Tags: rigid-body-simulation

[Blend file download (11MB)](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ihIVn5SmBiXZ5lYm6yBOGKbXnUspv42U/view?usp=sharing)

After importing the smartphone model through obj, the copy modifier plugin did not work well, so I just used Ctrl+J to merge the sub-objects into one and performed rigid simulation.

Compared to a cube of similar shape, the rotation due to falling is slow even though it was initially rotated 5 degrees as the cube. Also, it doesn't move any more suddenly around 270 frames.

Is this a problem with the way I imported the smartphone or the smartphone model?

(I tried mesh simulation but it is too laggy and shows strange moving, but it didnt stop anyway)

Comment: Your models are insanely large. The smartphone is 25.4 metres tall. Imagine a 7 floor apartment building falling over.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The simulation seems overall slow, because you are not using the right scale for objects while using accurate weights in the rigid body settings.

Do you remember the default cube you see each time you make a new scene in Blender? That cube is 2 meters on each side, it's bigger than a human being.
As of right now, your phone have a z dimension of 25.4m, that's as high as a six-story building:

[image]

What you can do is <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> → set 3D cursor to world origin, then set your pivot point to the 3D cursor:

[image]

Go through each object that have keyframes on their scale, right click their scale and hit Clear keyframes.

Select all your objects, ending by your phone, and scale it down until the dimension is something more accurate. Once done, hit <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> → apply scale.

You will need to redo the animation a bit, but it will be more accurate.